# Error in pdfminer library installation in conda environment

Tags: python-3.x, pdfminer

I installed "pdfminer" in virtual environment of conda.

I installed and reinstalled the library with following commands :

```
conda install -c conda-forge pdfminer
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 pdfminer
conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf202003 pdfminer
```

I got the same error all the time. It was like this:

```
/home/hamza/anaconda3/envs/my/bin/python /home/hamza/PycharmProjects/practice/pdf_info.py
20191125
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hamza/PycharmProjects/practice/pdf_info.py", line 67, in <module>
    from pdfminer.high_level import extract_text
  File "/home/hamza/anaconda3/envs/my/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdfminer/high_level.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .utils import open_filename
ImportError: cannot import name 'open_filename' from 'pdfminer.utils' (/home/hamza/anaconda3/envs/my/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pdfminer/utils.py)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Is there any alternate way to install this library or what we can do this resolve this error